# Changing the background color of only a portion of a cell in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a UserControl using .NET Framework 4.6.

I would like the background color of a cell in my DataGridView to be partially one color and partially another (i.e. the cell contains a curve; on the right side of the curve it is black. On the left side, it is white). Normally, I would use the following to change the background color of the cell:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[column].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

One idea that I considered, is adding a GraphicsPath object to the DataGridViewCell, but I have looked through the methods and have not found a way to do so.

Please let me know if you have any ideas about how to go about this.

If I cannot find a way to do so, I will probably just create an array of GraphicsPath objects. Alternatives are also welcomed.

Comment: There are a number of events such as `RowPrePaint` and others which can be used to change the color conditionally.  If you want to draw stuff there, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `CellPainting` event of `DataGridView` class you can draw any kind of background for cells

Example

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var cellBounds = e.CellBounds;

    // Left part of cell
    cellBounds.Width = cellBounds.Width / 2;

    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
    e.Graphics.SetClip(cellBounds);
    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);

    // draw all parts except background
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, 
        DataGridViewPaintParts.All & (~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background));

    // Right part of cell
    cellBounds.X = cellBounds.Right;

    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    e.Graphics.SetClip(cellBounds);
    e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);

    // draw all parts except background
    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, 
        DataGridViewPaintParts.All & (~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background));

    e.Handled = true;
}
```